# Como generar PDF desde HTML usando ItexSharp C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itextsharp

Buen día, estoy intentando generar un documento PDF desde una plantilla web que tengo diseñad, estoy usando ASP.net como tal tengo la función para generar el PDF.

```
                   Document DocumentoPDF = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(DocumentoPDF, Response.OutputStream);

                DocumentoPDF.Open();
                string plantilla = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/plantillas/CalculoInsentivo.htm"); //Corregir ruta
                DocumentoPDF.Add(new Paragraph("Hola este es un pdf"));           
                DocumentoPDF.Close();

                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + "filename=SIPRO_Calcula_Insentivo.pdf");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Write(DocumentoPDF);
                Response.End();
```

Solo se he logrado generar como tal un el siguiente PDF, sin la plantilla pre diseñada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*¿ Como puedo cargar correctamente la ruta de la plantilla, o bien, como puedo cambiar la función a fin de que se genere el contenido que deseo?*

Muchas gracias por la atención :D

Comment: iTextSharp no soporta html-to-pdf. Talvez usando iText7 te sirva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez llegue demasiado tarde pero esta solución puede ser para ti.

Efectivamente, como te dicen:

> iTextSharp no soporta html-to-pdf (Igmar Jovan Hernández)

Sin embargo existe la posibilidad de generar tal archivo, obteniendo todo el texto que existe dentro del archivo HTML y enviarlo directamente al archivo PDF que se genera previamente.

Para empezar con la solución previamente deberás cargar las librerías para este proceso:

ITextSharp : https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/

ITextSharp XML Worker: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp.xmlworker/

Básicamente con estas dos librerías podremos lograr el cometido, una vez agregadas al proyecto o solución procederemos a agregar dichas librerías al archivo:

```
//Librería de C#
using System.IO;

//Librería ITextSharp
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

//Librería iTextSharp XML Worker
using iTextSharp.tool.xml;
```

Una vez añadido las librerías que se van a ocupar, lo siguiente es crear el codigo que te va a permitir crear en concepto de HTML to PDF en C#:

```
//Plantilla HTML que se hará PDF
string htmlDestino = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "plantillas\\TuPlantilla.html"; 

//Lugar de Destino del PDF
string OutputPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "plantillas\\TuArchivo.pdf";

//Se crea una instancia la clase a ocupar para generar el PDF y al mismo tiempo se da el formato del tipo de hoja y sus respectivas dimensiones.
iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

//Se obtiene la carpeta donde se va a guardar el archivo PDF y al mismo instante se crea (en 0 kb por que aun no se llena de información)
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(OutputPath, FileMode.Create)); 

//Se abre el documento PDF que se creo previamente
pdfDoc.Open();

//Con esta instrucción empieza a llenarse el archivo PDF con datos de un XML para que se pueda interpretar en PDF y pueda darse el estilo correspondiente a tu plantilla de HTML.
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, new StreamReader(htmlDestino));

//Se cierra el archivo PDF que se estaba llenando de datos.
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Prueba sobre el archivo PDF:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe destacar que debes de configurar el estilo de archivo PDF (Margenes) para que dicho archivo tenga presentación.

Básicamente se hacen varias convenciones para este proceso

1) Archivo HTML -> XML  
2) XML -> Cadena (Texto del XML)
3) Cadena (Texto del XML) -> PDF

Espero esta solución pueda ser favorable no solo para ti, también para quien lo necesite.

Dudas sobre el código utilizado envíame correo electrónico: danielrg841@gmail.com

Quedo a tus ordenes. Saludos.